# Get original values from rolling sum in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rolling-computation

I got data describing the number of newly hospitalized persons for specific days and regions.
The number of hospitalized persons is the rolling sum of new hospitalized persons for the last 7 days.
The DataFrame looks like this:

```
Date         Region      sum_of_last_7_days
01.01.2020   1           1
02.01.2020   1           2
03.01.2020   1           3
04.01.2020   1           4
05.01.2020   1           5
06.01.2020   1           6
07.01.2020   1           7
08.01.2020   1           7
09.01.2020   1           7
01.01.2020   2           1
02.01.2020   2           2
03.01.2020   2           3
04.01.2020   2           4
05.01.2020   2           5
06.01.2020   2           6
07.01.2020   2           7
08.01.2020   2           7
09.01.2020   2           7
10.01.2020   2           4
```

The goal output is:

```
Date         Region      daily_new
01.01.2020   1           1
02.01.2020   1           1
03.01.2020   1           1
04.01.2020   1           1
05.01.2020   1           1
06.01.2020   1           1
07.01.2020   1           1
08.01.2020   1           0
09.01.2020   1           0
01.01.2020   2           1
02.01.2020   2           1
03.01.2020   2           1
04.01.2020   2           1
05.01.2020   2           1
06.01.2020   2           1
07.01.2020   2           1
08.01.2020   2           0
09.01.2020   2           0
10.01.2020   2           0
```

The way should be via **undo** the rolling sum operation with a window for 7 days, but I wasn't able to find any solution.

Comment: Your output is incorrect, if the cumsum is […, 6, 7, 7, 7], the input is […, x, 1, 0, 0]

Comment: @mozway: You need to take into account that it's the sum over a moving window, not a standard cumsum.

Answer (score 2):

To get the original, perform a `diff` and fill with the first value:

```
s = df.groupby('Region')['sum_of_last_7_days'].diff()
df['original'] = s.mask(s.isna(), df['sum_of_last_7_days'])
```

output:

```
          Date  Region  sum_of_last_7_days  original
0   01.01.2020       1                   1       1.0
1   02.01.2020       1                   2       1.0
2   03.01.2020       1                   3       1.0
3   04.01.2020       1                   4       1.0
4   05.01.2020       1                   5       1.0
5   06.01.2020       1                   6       1.0
6   07.01.2020       1                   7       1.0
7   08.01.2020       1                   7       0.0
8   09.01.2020       1                   7       0.0
9   01.01.2020       2                   1       1.0
10  02.01.2020       2                   2       1.0
11  03.01.2020       2                   3       1.0
12  04.01.2020       2                   4       1.0
13  05.01.2020       2                   5       1.0
14  06.01.2020       2                   6       1.0
15  07.01.2020       2                   7       1.0
16  08.01.2020       2                   7       0.0
17  09.01.2020       2                   7       0.0
```

Comment: I corrected the goal output. I think, that there is a problem with your solution because when we get to f.e. 10.01.2020 for region 2, where is sum_of_last_7_days 4 (0+0+1+1+1+1), the original should be zero, but you get -3 (4-7), don't you?